# How do I install Windows 11 to last 100 GB of my HDD?

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, arch-linux, windows-11

PC Setup:

- I have Arch Linux installed on the first 30 GB of my SSD. I have an HDD that I want to install Windows 11 on.

Want:

- On start up, I would like to choose to either boot into Arch Linux or Windows 11.

Tried:

- I currently have a Windows 11 iso on a USB partitioned with NTFS. I plug in the USB, restart the computer, hop into the UEFI BIOS and place all partitions of the USB higher in boot priority list. I save and exit the UEFI BIOS, but I still load into Arch Linux.
- I tried chainloading with GRUB, but couldn't seem to find the efi file on the USB.

  - *NOTE: I AM NOT FAMILIAR WITH GRUB AND CHAINLOADING*

Not sure where to go from here or what step I may be missing.

Current `lsblk` output:

```
- sda      |   465.3G | 
- sdb      |  119.2G  |
  - sdb1   |   512M   |   /efi
  - sdb2   |   30G    |   /
```

Comment: Usually, it's far easier to install Linux on a Windows OS drive than the converse. Whatever you try, **first make a disk image of the working arch SSD**, so you can revert to that i f Windows installation destroys the existing OS. You might also consider running Windows in VM.

Comment: Is installed Linux Legacy boot or UEFI? Assuming UEFI, try boot menu option instead of going into Firmware (BIOS/UEFI). Some UEFI’s may not be capable of booting off NTFS. Many do, some don’t. Default is FAT32. Use Rufus to create Windows 11 UEFI (GPT Scheme) bootable pen drive. It will create a small FAT32 partition with bootloader and NTFS driver to seamlessly start Windows boot off NTFS pen drive. You will have to disable Secure Boot as well for the time being.

Comment: Above  comment may only address how to start Windows boot process. How to install in last 100 GB space needs to be done using proper partitioning during setup.

Comment: @patkim Not really. If the 100GB are unallocated space, not a partition, the installer will be perfectly happy to create all the partitions it wants there.

Comment: @MrDrago9 Keep in mind Windows 11 do NOT support Legacy mode or MBR. So, first of all, you need GPT and Arch properly installed in UEFI mode as it should be since 2012.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - OP has not provided partition layout of HDD. All they say is they want to install in last 100GB of HDD and they have Linux on separate SSD. Is the last 100GB the only free space or they have say 500GB free space but want last 100 for System drive is unclear. Hence the comment.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I believe that I have GPT already for my Arch partition.
@patkim,  I do have 500 GB free space and want the last 100 GB for Windows 11.
I updated the post with my current `lsblk` output

Comment: You just need to create a partition of type `Microsoft Basic Data` with e.g. `gdisk`, which allows you to start the partition somewhere you want. (It's also possible in `diskpart.exe`) Then in Windows Setup you should be able choose to install to it (WS should split it into the main partition and the recovery partition and format them for you automatically). But apparently the problem you are having is that you can't even boot the installation USB drive...

Comment: Note that after Windows installation the Windows Boot Manager will be registered and prioritized to the top by most (if not all) UEFI firmware automatically (Microsoft-domination toxicity). So you'll need to change the boot order in your UEFI setting (or by booting into Linux via Advanced Startup in Windows and using `efibootmgr`; or maybe bcdedit can do as well) after that to boot to grub by default, where WBM can be chainloaded.

Comment: Indeed, as @TomYan mentions, the question title doesn't match the actual question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I may be misunderstanding what I have to do to get going. I have Windows 11 iso file on usb. I would like to install Windows 11 to the last 100 GB of my HDD. For some reason, I was thinking that I would be able to boot into the usb and then install Windows 11 from there, but I'm not sure that is correct. I know how to partition with `gdisk`, but I still feel as if I am missing a step here.

Comment: You need to boot from installation media in order to install. How or where is two or three steps after that. The problem you describe in the text is not being able to boot and the mentions of partitions suggest you did it - the installation media - wrong, there shouldn't be partitions plural, there should be A partition and it's not that partition but the drive itself that has to be recognized as bootable in a UEFI system. So, start by using proper installation media. Your problem clearly has nothing to do (yet) with what you wrote in the tile.

Comment: Prferably use a Windows computer and the official Media Creation tool that's triggered when downloading the ISO. In Linux you have very few options with the current batch of Microsoft ISO that deviate a lot from the standard therefore usual tools DON'T work. MKUSB would be a suggestion for any Debian or derivative but not an option for Arch. Ventoy is a nice multi ISO bootloader: Install it to the USB stick then simply copy the Windows ISO to its root.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I agree with you that I have probably improperly setup the installation media. I ran `mkfs.ntfs` to ensure that the USB could be used with a Windows based computer. I used my roommates Windows computer to both download the ISO and copy the ISO to the USB. I then tried to boot into the USB  on my computer that already has a GPT ( with Arch Linux and ext4 filesystem on the first 30 GB ) with no luck.

Comment: If you did it from a Windows PC why didn't you made the USB installer right there, with the official tool that's triggered by the download itself? That's the only official way although the option I mentioned above are fine, I've personally tested both many times. *copy the ISO to the USB* will NEVER work, be it the Windows ISO or any Linux, end of story.

Comment: Maybe that is part of my confusion. I realize now that the ISO is a copy of a disc image and not the installation assistant. I will look into putting the installation assistant onto the USB. (1) Would the installation assistant need to be for an NTFS file system or ext4 file system? (2) How would I go about running the installation assistant? Do I run it while booted into Arch? (3) Just for clarification, shouldn't I have been able to boot into the USB with the ISO?

Comment: In the case of UEFI, you should mount the ISO on Linux and copy all the files to the formatted USB. You should be able to boot it when selecting boot to USB on the UEFI boot menu (not grub) then. (While not required by the spec AFAIK, in reality most UEFI firmware, if not all, should have NTFS driver. I have no idea what Microsoft expects you to do in case your UEFI doesn't, since they don't seem to care about the fact that install.wim going over 4GB, exceeding the file size limit of FAT32.)